# How do you comment out an entire class in Java?

Tags: java

Not saying I would ever need this but how do you comment out an entire class after something like:

```
public class yadayada extends yadayadasquared {

    /**
     * Says Hello
     **/
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

When there are nicely commented / documented methods within the class?

Let's imagine that it's for only for five minutes to avoid having the whole fork discussion....

And yes, you durned purists, I saw this!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123423/do-you-leave-historical-code-commented-out-in-classes-that-you-update

Let's assume this is for a 5 minute test. Repo work for that? Nope. Delete? Love the control-slash suggestion.

Comment: Why would you need to?  Remove/rename the file to prevent it from being built, or exclude it from the build in your IDE/Ant/Maven script.

Comment: Press CTRL-A, then CTRL-SHIFT-7 in Eclipse :) Undo using same sequence again or CTRL-Z.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Define "entire class".

Select the class's contents, hit <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd><sup>*</sup>, and your IDE should single-line comment everything. This way you still have the class available, just without functionality. Or select the entire class. Or rename the file. Or... but ultimately, what's the point? Delete the file.

<sup>* Or whatever your IDE's sequence for single-line commenting is.</sup>

Comment: Perhaps he means to ``deprecrate`` the entire class. One example for this would be, say, switching from a local Oracle database to an MsSQL database on a Spring Boot application. Deprecating the OracleConfiguration class for example would prevent an exception looking for a connection to Oracle (you may want to switch back to it later and hence save the code). Commenting the entire thing out would also work but it's less elegant.

Comment: @santafebound  OP explicitly means commenting and gives a hypothetical five-minute test example. Deprecating serves a different purpose and would not have the same behavior.

Comment: Single-line comment is good option. May be he can not delete because the code was checked out from the code repo and he is not the working on this part. Rather this code is creating issue to build and test his own code. So he wants to keep the file but temporarily comment out the content to be able to test is own code.

Answer (score 2):

if using an ide: one can do "<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>", and then do "<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>", and that will comment out all of the code.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation comments, or any multiline commnent, will be a problem if you use a multiline comment enclosing the class body, since they finish with `*/`, but modern IDEs have some shortcuts to comment/uncoment code. In NetBeans, you just need to mark the code and type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>. So, I would comment what I need, use the code and than undo the changes (comments). Renaming the file extension would be a good thing too as `@su-` said.

Comment: Eclipse can add & remove `//` to all selected lines with CTRL+SHIFT+C or CTRL+7 or CTRL+/ (see "Toggle Comment" in shortcuts)

Comment: Nice! Let me see if NetBeans has it too.

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse you can use `Ctrl+/` to toggle single-line comments on selected lines. If you're using another IDE you probably have something similar. Just select the entire class and hit the hotkey!

Answer (score 1):

A quick alternative to the comment-solution is to just rename the file to `MyClass.java.txt` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the multiple line comment `/*`

```
/*public class Foo extends Bar
{
    public string SayFoo()
    {
        return "Foo";
    }
}*/
```

However if your code contains documentation and you are using an IDE, most of them support a "Toggle Comment" feature. I know Eclipse and Netbeans both support that feature.

But the real solution is to use some kind of version control system which will track your code for you. I would recommend git since is doesn't need a server to use.

Comment: This will only take you down to the next set of comments.

Comment: Durned version control for a 5 minute test. No way man! Not going to clog up the system with that. But great suggestion for a longer term solution. Thats @Stephan (thanks for the edit too!

Answer (score 0):

Try this in `Eclipse IDE`... Select the **body of the code** within the Class body. (ie. `between {  and  }` )

**To Comment:**

```
             Ctrl + Shift + /
```

**To Uncommend:**

```
             Ctrl + Shift + \
```

Answer (score -1):

What about

```
@Deprecated
```

Does that work?

Comment: Nope, same answer as above. It only takes you down to the next comment section.